# getaddrinfo() returning 2.0.0.0

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to find the IP address of a hostname i.e. www.google.com

i call getaddrinfo() scan the list, create a raw ipv4 icmp socket, then i bind the socket to the address

when i check the packets being sent in wireshark, the address is diplayed as 2.0.0.0 no matter what hostname i pass to getaddrinfo()

```
  int                  skt, errno;
   struct sockaddr_in   addr;
   struct addrinfo      hints;  //prefered addr type(connection)
   struct addrinfo  *   list;   //list of addr structs
   struct addrinfo  *   addrptr;//the one i am gonna use

   struct in_addr test;

    if(servname == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "No servname!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /*
     * prefered connection type
     */

    bzero(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_flags                = 0;
    hints.ai_family               = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype             = SOCK_RAW;
    hints.ai_protocol             = IPPROTO_ICMP;                 

    /*get IP*/
    if((errno = getaddrinfo(servname, 0, &hints, &list))<0){
        fprintf(stderr, "addrinfo error, lookup fail:  %s",
        gai_strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

   addrptr=list;
   //start scanning 
   while(addrptr){
       //start
       if((skt = socket(addrptr->ai_family, addrptr->ai_socktype, addrptr->ai_protocol))<0){
        perror("socket()");
        exit(1);
       }
           if(skt > 0)
            if(connect(skt,addrptr->ai_addr, addrptr->ai_addrlen)==0)
                break;
            printf("attempt connect\n");
            close (skt);
            addrptr=addrptr->ai_next;
    }


 //once IP has been found set destination address an port=0
 dstaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = ((struct in_addr *)addrptr->ai_addr)->s_addr;
 dstaddr.sin_port        = 0;
```

Comment: Have you tried using `gethostbybname()` for translating your host name into an IP address? `getaddrinfo()` uses this function internally.

Comment: this is for a courework assignment on my networking course, and they have kind have made a bit of emphyses on using getaddrinfo(), as its the 'modern' method.

Comment: @Babbleshack And they are right. `gethostbyname()` should not be used any longer, at least in new programs. It is better to use `getaddrinfo()` and `getnameinfo()`; they cover everything you might want to accomplish.

Comment: Okay so i have figured that i am receiving the IP address correctly howerver i am copying the data addrptr, to dstaddr incorectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be some errors in your code:

- `addrptr=list->ai_next` should be `addrptr=addr->ai_next` to traverse the list.
- After the while-loop, `addrptr->ai_addr` holds the last found entry, not `list->ai_addr`.
- `bind()` returns zero on *success*, so you should check with `if(bind(...) == 0) break;`
- Unless I am mistaken, `bind()` is for binding a socket to a local address.
  To check if the host can be reached at some address, use `connect()` instead.

This is the code that I tried:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int                  skt, errno;
    struct addrinfo      hints;  //prefered addr type(connection)
    struct addrinfo  *   list;   //list of addr structs
    struct addrinfo  *   addrptr;//the one i am gonna use

    char *servname = "www.google.com";

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_flags                = 0;
    hints.ai_family               = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype             = SOCK_RAW;
    hints.ai_protocol             = IPPROTO_ICMP;

    if ((errno = getaddrinfo(servname, 0, &hints, &list))<0){
        fprintf(stderr, "addrinfo error, lookup fail:  %s", gai_strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    for (addrptr = list; addrptr != NULL; addrptr = addrptr->ai_next) {
        if ((skt = socket(addrptr->ai_family, addrptr->ai_socktype, addrptr->ai_protocol)) == -1)
            continue;
        if(connect(skt,addrptr->ai_addr, addrptr->ai_addrlen) == 0)
            break;
        close (skt);
    }

    if (addrptr != NULL) {
        char host[NI_MAXHOST];
        getnameinfo(addrptr->ai_addr, addrptr->ai_addrlen, host, sizeof(host), NULL, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST);
        printf("%s can be reached at %s\n", servname, host);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is: "www.google.com can be reached at 173.194.113.146"

*Update:* Your code to copy the found address is wrong, it should be

```
struct sockaddr_in dstaddr;
memcpy(&dstaddr, addrptr->ai_addr, sizeof(dstaddr));
dstaddr.sin_port        = 0;
```

Comment: thanks, i have already made the first change,  i just forgot to update the quuestion.

I will make the others an see what happens

Comment: i am looking through some notes, and as far as i can tell i am supposed to be using bind, but i cant find a reason why; or figure one out.

Neither bind or connect succed beforet the list runs out.

Comment: @Babbleshack: I have tested the code with `if(connect(skt,addrptr->ai_addr, addrptr->ai_addrlen) == 0) break;` and it returned a valid IP-address (173.194.113.146) for www.google.com. Note that you have to check with `== 0` for success.

Comment: I dont think so i have no firewall software installed, i am using a linux box.

Comment: @Babbleshack: Have you tried with if(connect(...) **== 0**) break ?

Comment: I should mention the socket connects, the problem is, the returned adress is always 2.0.0.0; irrespective of the hostname i pass it.

Comment: @Babbleshack: I checked the found address with `char host[NI_MAXHOST]; getnameinfo(addrptr->ai_addr, addrptr->ai_addrlen, host, sizeof(host), NULL, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST); printf("address=%s\n", host);` .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41771/discussion-between-babbleshack-and-martin-r)

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, this happens when casting

```
struct sockaddr_in dest;
struct addrinfo* ainfo_arr;

/*getaddrinfo(hostname,NULL,&hints,&ainfo_arr);*/

dest = *( (struct sockaddr_in*) ainfo_arr);
//casting addrinfo to sockaddr_in
```

instead of

```
struct sockaddr_in dest;
struct addrinfo* ainfo_arr;

/*getaddrinfo(hostname,NULL,&hints,&ainfo_arr);*/

dest = *( (struct sockaddr_in*) ainfo_arr->ai_addr);
//casting sockaddr to sockaddr_in
```

so data in `dest` is invalid

(probably `AF_PACKET` https://stackoverflow.com/a/40254078/6569209)