# I get wrong ip address with getifaddrs

Tags: c, linux

**Function to get ethernet specified ip address:**

```
char *get_ethernet_ip(const char *ethernet, char *ip, size_t len) {
    struct ifaddrs *ips;
    int rc = getifaddrs(&ips);
    if (rc == -1) {
        SYSLOG("getifaddrs() failed (%s)", strerror(errno));
        return NULL;
    }

    for (; ips != NULL; ips = ips->ifa_next) {
        if (strcasecmp(ethernet, ips->ifa_name) == 0) {
            in_addr local_ip = ((sockaddr_in *)ips->ifa_addr)->sin_addr;
            const char *p = inet_ntop(AF_INET, &local_ip, ip, len);
            if (p == NULL) {
                SYSLOG("inet_ntop() failed (%s)", strerror(errno));
                return NULL;
            }

            return ip;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

**Used in main:**

```
char ip[32];
SYSLOG("ethernet lo ip: %s", get_ethernet_ip("lo", ip, 32));
SYSLOG("ethernet eth0 ip: %s", get_ethernet_ip("eth0", ip, 32));
```

**Result:**
*[ 2016-10-26 04:37:52 UTC ] [ server_info.cpp:90 ] [ main ] ethernet lo ip: 1.0.0.0

[ 2016-10-26 04:37:52 UTC ] [ server_info.cpp:91 ] [ main ] ethernet eth0 ip: 2.0.0.0*

**Question:**
The ip for `lo` should be `127.0.0.1`, and for `eth0` it should not be `2.0.0.0`, am I right?

Comment: I know I haven't called `freeifaddrs()`. No need to point out.

Comment: You should at least show the definition of `ip` so we know it's sane.

Comment: @paddy Re-edited. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have assumed that the first entry you encounter for a name will be in the `AF_INET` family, but you did not check.

Use `ips->ifa_addr->sa_family` to check that it's `AF_INET`.

Chances are that the first `lo` and `eth0` devices you encounter will be in the `AF_PACKET` family.